# JavaScript - Grouping items into arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a JavaScript array that is something like this:

```
var items = [
 { id:1, group:'Produce', name:'Apple', weight: 0.5 },
 { id:2, group:'Produce', name:'Banana', weight: 0.2 },
 { id:3, group:'Meat', name:'Beef', weight: 1.0 },
 { id:4, group:'Meat', name:'Chicken', weight: 0.75 },
 { id:5, group:'Dairy', name:'Milk', weight:1.0 }
];
```

I want to look through this array and dynamically put them in arrays by their group. I tried the following, however, it didn't work:

```
var groups = [];
for (var i = 0; i<items.length; i++) {
  var groupName = items[i].group;
  if (groups.includes(groupName) === false) {
    groups[groupName] = new Array();
  }
  groups[groupName].push(items[i]);
}
```

Basically, I'm trying to create a Hashtable in JavaScript. The key is the group name and the value is an `Array` of items in that group. However, I've been unsuccessful. What am I missing here?

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: "It didn't work" and "I've been unsuccessful" are not acceptable problem statements. Please clearly define the problem, and make the title describe it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `groups` should be an object.

Then you're testing `groups.includes(groupName)` but it is [an array function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes), and you're creating an hashtable.

Instead, check if the key exists on the object with `groups[groupName] === undefined`.

```
var groups = {};
for (var i = 0; i<items.length; i++) {
  var groupName = items[i].group;
  if (groups[groupName] === undefined) {
    groups[groupName] = new Array();
  }
  groups[groupName].push(items[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you following simple solution.

```js
var items = [
 { id:1, group:'Produce', name:'Apple', weight: 0.5 },
 { id:2, group:'Produce', name:'Banana', weight: 0.2 },
 { id:3, group:'Meat', name:'Beef', weight: 1.0 },
 { id:4, group:'Meat', name:'Chicken', weight: 0.75 },
 { id:5, group:'Dairy', name:'Milk', weight:1.0 }
], obj = {};

items.forEach(c => (obj[c.group] || (obj[c.group] = [])).push(c));

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use just an object and check if the key exist. If not take a new array.

```js
var items = [{ id: 1, group: 'Produce', name: 'Apple', weight: 0.5 }, { id: 2, group: 'Produce', name: 'Banana', weight: 0.2 }, { id: 3, group: 'Meat', name: 'Beef', weight: 1.0 }, { id: 4, group: 'Meat', name: 'Chicken', weight: 0.75 }, { id: 5, group: 'Dairy', name: 'Milk', weight:1.0 }],
    groups = Object.create(null),          // take a really empty object
    groupName,
    i;
    
for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    groupName = items[i].group;
    if (!groups[groupName]) {              // check if the key in object exists
        groups[groupName] = [];            // if not, assign an empty array
    }
    groups[groupName].push(items[i]);
}

console.log(groups);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to use reduce:

```js
var items = [
 { id:1, group:'Produce', name:'Apple', weight: 0.5 },
 { id:2, group:'Produce', name:'Banana', weight: 0.2 },
 { id:3, group:'Meat', name:'Beef', weight: 1.0 },
 { id:4, group:'Meat', name:'Chicken', weight: 0.75 },
 { id:5, group:'Dairy', name:'Milk', weight:1.0 }
];

const grouped = items.reduce((accum, item) => {
 accum[item.group] = accum[item.group] ? accum[item.group].concat(item) : [item];
 return accum;
}, {});

console.log(grouped);
```

Answer (score 0):

I alwasy use lodash or underscore

But however, try this using reduce function

```
 var items = [
   { id:1, group:'Produce', name:'Apple', weight: 0.5 },
     { id:2, group:'Produce', name:'Banana', weight: 0.2 },
     { id:3, group:'Meat', name:'Beef', weight: 1.0 },
     { id:4, group:'Meat', name:'Chicken', weight: 0.75 },
     { id:5, group:'Dairy', name:'Milk', weight:1.0 }
 ];

 Array.prototype.groupDynamically = function(prop) {
   return this.reduce(function(groups, item) {
     var val = item[prop];
     groups[val] = groups[val] || [];
     groups[val].push(item);
     return groups;
   }, {});
 }

 //Then in your case say

var groups = items.groupDynamically('group');
```